# How does this loop work?

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

I wanted the below loop to increment the pointer until encountering the null-terminating character. It doesn't work correctly, though.

```
while (*s++ != '\0')
    ;
```

This one does:

```
while (*s != '\0')
    s++;
```

I can't seem to understand what is the difference between the two.

This question is related to exercise 5.3 of `The C Programming Language` book.

Comment: `++` will increment the value *after* evaluation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is the state of the pointer after the loop.

In the first example you point one after the 0 character, and in the second you point at the 0 character.

Answer (score 7):

```
while (*s++ != '\0')
    ;
```

The above statement will increase the value of `s` whether `(*s++ != '\0')` returns false or true. If false, it will increment it as well, but it will break out of the loop anyway.

```
while (*s != '\0')
    s++;
```

The above statement won't increase the value of `s` if `(*s != '\0')` returns false, then breaking out of the loop, making so that `*s` still keeps pointing to `'\0'`.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: When happens the `++` in both cases, and when doesn't it? Especially in the last loop run?

Let's have a look: In the last loop run, the expression between `()` is evaluated.

In the first example, this means the `++` is executed, having `s` point after the `NUL` byte.

In the second example, there is no `++` in the `()`, and the loop body isn't executed any longer. So `++` does not happen, having `s` point to the `NUL` byte.

Answer (score 0):

The "++" is an increment operator which functions very similar to "s += 1" or "s = s + 1" although ++ does increment s by 1, position of the operator will effect the outcome. Observe below:

```
int  x;
int  y;

// Increment operators
x = 1;
y = ++x;    // x is now 2, y is also 2
y = x++;    // x is now 3, y is 2
```

The difference is in whether you want to increment the value to be set "pre"(Before) or post(after) evaluation(retrieval of the value).